# c# Verify the certificate's signature using the nominated public key

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, x509certificate2

i have 1x X509Certificate2 with a Publickey (x509certificate_1)
Now i created a new X509Certificate2 and try to Verify it.

```
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate x509certificate_11 = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509certificate_1);
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate x509certificate_22 = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509certificate_2);
x509certificate_22.Verify(x509certificate_11.GetPublicKey());
```

ERROR: Public key presented not for certificate signature

Can somebody explain me, how to verify my x509certificate_2 to x509certificate_1?

Comment: x509certificate_2 was created by me